# Exporting data from SSRS to a .csv file adds lots of quotation marks how do I get just one set?

Tags: csv, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report which is just a simple SELECT statement which generates a list of columns full of data. I want this data to be exported as a CSV file with each datum being enclosed in " quotation marks. I have created a table and used this as my expression

```
   =""""+Fields!Activity_Code.Value+""""
```

When I run the report inside ReportBuilder 3.0 I get exactly what I'm looking for

[image]

No headers and each datum has quotation marks, perfect.

But when I hit export to csv, and then open with notepad I see this.

[image]

The headers are in there where they shouldn't be and each datum has 3 quotation marks on each side. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal.

When csv fields contain a separator or double quotes, the fields are enclosed in double quotes and the quotes inside the fields are escaped with another quote.

Example - the fields:

```
123
"27" monitor"
456
```

become:

```
123,"""27"" monitor""",456
```

or:

```
"123","""27"" monitor""","456"
```

A csv reader/parser should handle this correctly when reading the data (or you could provide a parameter telling the parser that the fields are quoted).

---

On the other hand, if you just want your fields to be quoted inside the csv (and not visible after opening the file), you can tell the csv generator to quote the fields (or in this case do nothing since the generator seems to be adding quotes already).

Comment: "(or you could provide a parameter telling the parser that the fields are quoted)"

is it possible for you to go into this in some more detail? I'm a bit confused by what you mean here.

Comment: @tomdemaine Most parsers/readers will autodetect the quotes around the fields and the escaped quotes inside them - those will be 'removed' before viewing. In some cases you have to specify a parameter to make the parser do that. In this case it looks like ReportBuilder removes those quotes automatically (only a single double quote left). But you probably just want to do a plain export (without that expression to add additional quotes) - this will put quotes around the fields in the csv file and those will not be visible when opening with ReportBuilder for example.